# Dynamically long downloads?

Tags: php, dynamic, download

so I have seen this at a few places and sites, that file downloads don't seem to specify a Content-Length, so the download continues until the server stops sending data.

Now I was wondering how I could achieve something like that with PHP, when I'm sending dynamically generated files through a PHP-script for download.

I've done some research but couldn't really find anything.

(As a specific **example**: I would like to let a user download a ZIP-file while it's still being built.)

So, how do I create a dynamically long download without the serverside knowing how long it'll turn out?

Comment: Just... don't send a Content-Length header and start outputting data?

Comment: Yes, if you don't send a length, then clients won't be able to see download progress in the usual bar-graph form. But it will still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, you could just skip sending `Content-Length` header. This function can come in handy:

```
function force_download($file){
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); <--- Don't send length
    readfile($file);
}
```